# Dot product with remarkable identities only

Tags: vectors, inner-products

I’m studying and doing an exercise from a school textbook. The wording is the following : $\triangle ABC$ is a triangle, $||AB|| = 3$, $||BC|| = 5$, and $||AC|| = 6.$ Calculate $AB ⋅ AC$. I couldn’t come up with a result using remarkable identities which seems the only method to use here. (By isolating the dot product on the right side of the equation).
$$
||AB + AC||^2  
= ||AB||^2 + 2 AB ⋅ AC + ||AC||^2.
$$
I’m stuck here. How will I replace $||AB+AC||^2$ knowing that I can’t just put $AB$ and $AC$ and then square it. I can’t use triangle inequalities since $-BA + AC$ is different than $-BC$? What can I do. The textbook correction says the result is $10$ but there’s no detail. Any answer appreciated.

Comment: If $AB$ and similar are vectors, then are the norms given? If so, you should say that $||AB|| = 3$ and similar.

Comment: You’re right I’ll edit it. @SeanRoberson

Comment: Hint: square $\overrightarrow{BC}=\overrightarrow{AC}-\overrightarrow{AB}$.

Comment: $$AB\cdot AC=|AB|\cdot |AC|\cdot \cos \angle A$$
Use the law of cosines to determine $\cos \angle A.$

Comment: We have no angle tho. That’s why I’m afraid remarkable identities is the only way since we’ve only been taught to use this when we don’t have the angle (in addition to multiplying coordinates but it’s not the case here because of the plane). @ThomasAndrews

Comment: What are "remarkable identities?"

Comment: You definitely have an angle, you just don't know it yet. Luckily, the law of cosines lets you figure out the cosine of the angle.

Comment: It could be related to the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. Its the literal french translation so it might sound weird. But this is a remarkable identity for example. (a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2.

Comment: @Gribouillis how could I exploit it here ?

Comment: @kwiky use that $\|BC\| = \|BA + AC\|$

Comment: I used the substraction remarkable identity and I found the correct result. ||AC-AB||^2 then I replaced BC when I had to plug the values. Thanks everyone for your answers.

Comment: @Gribouillis Yep this actually works too, thanks. I retain from this exercice that polarisation identity doesn’t work when it’s a negative vector added to another vector. Might be late for the test that is tomorrow but ig it’s better than nothing…

Comment: @Somos the message has been edited by someone and an error has been made, but it was originally ||AC|| = 6

Comment: @kwiky Thanks! I restored it to 6.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

> $\triangle ABC$ is a triangle, $||AB|| = 3$, $||BC|| = 5$, and $||AC|| = 6.$ Calculate $AB \cdot AC$.

You were close, but there is a sign difference to notice.

By definition of a
[Euclidean vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector)
as directed line segment, $\vec{AB} := \vec{B}-\vec{A}$
is the vector from point $A$ to point $B$.
Then, from the given side lengths get

$$ 3 = ||AB|| = ||\vec{AB}|| = ||\vec{B}-\vec{A}|| =
  ||\vec{A}-\vec{B}|| = ||\vec{BA}||. \tag1$$

Also, similarly given side lengths, get

$$ 5 = ||BC|| = ||\vec{BC}|| = ||\vec{B} -\vec{C}|| = 
 ||\vec{B} -\vec{A} + \vec{A} - \vec{C}|| = 
||\vec{BA} +\vec{AC}||. \tag2$$

Then use the dot product to get

$$ \vec{BC}\cdot\vec{BC} = ||\vec{BC}||^2 =
||\vec{BA} +\vec{AC}||^2 = ||\vec{BA}||^2 +
 2 \vec{BA} \cdot \vec{AC} + ||\vec{AC}||^2. \tag3$$

Substitute the given side lengths in equation $(3)$ and
move squares to the left side to get

$$ 5^2 - 3^2 - 6^2 = -20 = 2 \vec{BA} \cdot \vec{AC}. \tag4$$
But now, easily get

$$ \vec{BA}= \vec{A}-\vec{B}= -(\vec{B}-\vec{A})= -\vec{AB}. \tag5 $$

Combining equations $(4)$ and $(5)$, the answer is

$$ 10 = -\vec{BA} \cdot \vec{AC} = \vec{AB} \cdot \vec{AC}. \tag6 $$

Comment: $3+6=9\neq5$ was obvious -- How do you reason about your norm BA arrow plus AC arrow? Why would that be 5? I know you can't just add the norms but how do you know the norm of that is 5?

Comment: @Snared Thanks for that comment! Please read my edited answer,

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems at first a bit complicated so I’ll walk through it slowly and ask if I have a question.

Comment: @Somos ok so here is what I’ve had some difficulty to understand reading the answer. How do you know vector BA =  A - B ? Same here. =||BC→||=||B⃗−C⃗||=||B⃗−A⃗+A⃗−C⃗||=||BA→+AC→||. I don’t imagine myself being able to imagine this during a test.I could find BA + AC easily of course, but how to convert with your notation B-A + A-C ? Is vector BA = B-A ? And here BA→=A⃗−B⃗=−(B⃗−A⃗)=−AB. Is any vector equal to its end of the vector minus the starting point ? I understand that -BA = AB tho. But I’d like if you give advice and explanation on the notation of decomposing vectors with letters. Thanks

Comment: @kwiky You may find the answer to [MSE question 2728060](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2728060) clears your confusion.

Comment: @Somos I’ll read this