# Why are the vector coordinates calculated this way?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Suppose we are given a vector $\vec{AB}$, where $A(x_1;y_1)$ and $B(x_2;y_2)$. Why do we calculate its coordinates as $\vec{AB}(x_2-x_1;y_2-y_1)$? And how can a segment have "coordinates" at all?

Comment: These are not "coordinates" you are calculating here, but the vector between the points. They use the same notation as it lets you swap between a point and the position vector of that point. You can derive your identity by starting at $A$, going to the origin (i.e. applying the position vector of $A$ in reverse, i.e. applying $-A$), and then going to $B$ (i.e. applying the position vector of $B$). This means that $\vec{AB}=(-A)+B=B-A$ as required.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When we go from $(x_1, y_1)$ to $(x_2, y_2)$ we are simultaneously going from $x_1$ to $x_2$ and from $y_1$ to $y_2$ . If we start at $x_1$ and end up at $x_2$, we travel $x_2-x_1$ units in the $x$ direction. Drawing a picture may help.

Comment: I think, we covered this problem in the middle school... It is a geometrical problem. You have to draw to understand it. Draw XOY system of coordinates. Draw $\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OB}$. Use the rules of vector subtraction to draw $\vec{AB}$. Project all three vectors on the axes of coordinates. Measure the projections. You'll clearly see why $\vec{AB} = (x_B-x_A, y_B-y_A)$. If just "seeing" that is not enough for you, it is a trivial exercise in planimetrics to show that's true.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, given two points $A=(x_1;y_1)$ and $B=(x_2;y_2)$, by definition vector $\vec{AB}$ is the vector such that

$$\vec{OA}+\vec{AB}=\vec{OB}$$

therefore

$$\vec{AB}=\vec{OB}-\vec{OA}=(x_2-x_1;y_2-y_1)$$

that is vector $\vec{AB}$ has components $x_2-x_1$ along $x$ axis and $y_2-y_1$ along $y$ axis.

Note that $\vec{AB}$ is not a segment but we can consider it as a directed line segment in the plane or more in general in the space.

See also the related

- [Vectors and directed line segments](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2728060/505767)

Comment: In my school textbook, it first says that the coordinates of a vector are defined as the difference between the end and start coordinates. Only then is the triangle rule for vector addition given, which is proved through the definition of the vector coordinate

Comment: @gryna That's fine. There is not a general unique way to proceed for the definition. The geometrical approch is sometimes used at first, in 2D or 3D case, because it is simpler to visualize, personally I prefer this way for a first definition. But also an algebraic or analytical approch is fine. Of course both are very important at the end.